# My 2D Array in C is empty after populating it in a while loop, but within the loop it appears populated correctly

Tags: arrays, c, memory, multidimensional-array

I am new to C, and I'm trying to populate a 2D array by breaking a text file of instructions into sub-strings and storing them into it. This loop is to populate said Array, within the while loop, it prints perfectly fine and seems to store it correctly. After the while loop, the 2D array is now empty and I do not understand why.

I should not have to allocate memory from the Heap as this is all within the same function correct? If I'm wrong, please let me know what I should be doing instead, thank you.

My goal is to have an instruction like

> mul 2 4

be stored into

```
instructionArr[0][0] = mul 
instructionArr[0][1] = 2 
instructionArr[0][2] = 4
```

Is this the correct way to even go about this?

```
char instruction[256];
char* instructionArr[100][5];

int line = 0;

while(fgets(instruction, 256, fp) != NULL) {

    printf("%s", instruction);

    char* tokenized = strtok(instruction, " ");

    int count = 0;

    while (tokenized != NULL) {

        printf("tokenized: line: %d, position: %d is: %s\n", line, count, tokenized);

        instructionArr[line][count] = tokenized;

        //Prints string correctly
        printf("tokenizedArr[%d][%d] = %s\n", line, count, instructionArr[line][count]);

        tokenized = strtok(NULL, " ");

        count ++;
    }

    line ++;
}

//Print the first element of instructionArr, [0][0], should be a string, but is nothing.
printf("tokenizedArr[%d][%d] = %s\n", 0, 0, instructionArr[0][0]);
```

Comment: Tip: Before you footgun yourself, try and define constants like `256` somewhere so you can use them consistently, like `#define BUFFER_SIZE 256` and then use that.

Comment: "the first element of instructionArr, [0][0], should be a string" In your own words, *why*? What is the type of `instructionArr`? Therefore, what is the type of `instructionArr[0]`? Therefore, what is the type of `instructionArr[0][0]`?

Comment: There are multiple logical errors here. It seems that you do not understand that the `char` type is *not a "string"* and in fact represents a *single character*. Or at least, if you do understand that, you haven't properly accounted for it.

Comment: The first element of insturctionArr[0][0] should be a string because that is what I have attempted to store into it. instructionArr is an array of char's correct? Is that a string in C?  instructionArr is a 2D array of characters, oh... I think I see the error, I'm not storing 100x5 STRINGS, I'm storing 100x5 Characters, that is the issue here?

Comment: Ah I realized I had an error, it should be char* instructionArr[100][5]; not char instructionArr[100][5]; However, my issue remains

Comment: `char* instructionArr[100][5];` declares an 2D array of *Uninitialized* Pointers. That means each element expects a valid memory address where a `char` is stored. So long as all of your inputs are 4-chars long (or less), then `char instructionArr[100][5];` will store `100` of those small strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtok modifies the string it operates on.
See https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/STR06-C.+Do+not+assume+that+strtok%28%29+leaves+the+parse+string+unchanged

Also you should probably use strcpy() instead of "instructionArr[line][count] = tokenized;"

EDIT: strncpy() is safer

Comment: Simply changing to `strcpy` would not be a good idea as the left hand side currently does not point anywhere